# TYPO3 7.6.18. $this->request->getArguments() shows not all params

Tags: typo3, fluid, extbase

The link looks like this: `/index.php?id=17&L=0&tx_gbpartner_partnerlisting[category]=11&tx_gbpartner_partnerlisting[@widget_0][currentPage]=3`

Who can say me, why does `DebuggerUtility::var_dump($this->request->getArguments());` only show the parameter `category`?

What is wrong with `tx_gbpartner_partnerlisting[@widget_0][currentPage]=3` ?
Why doesn't extbase "understand" this parameter?

Answer (score 3):

When in Extbase, `$this->request` contains *filtered arguments for your specific controller action, in the scope of plugin name* and as such, they do not contain arguments that were not targeted at your plugin. The widget parameter is one such parameter (it gets processed by the WidgetController belonging to your Widget).

To correctly declare and use arguments for controller actions, declare them as parameters for the action method and add any PHPDoc that may be required to know the type and so on.